# How to deploy to ECS when an image is pushed to ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

My use case is very simple, but all the tutorials I find do the whole push → build → push to ecr → deploy. I already have a bitbucket pipeline that builds and pushes the image to ECR and what I need is some way of detecting that a new image was pushed, then updating my ECS tasks with the new image. So far this is how my `CodePipeline` pipeline looks like:

[image]

And this is how my Deploy step looks like:

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

Moreover, how can I continuously update my ECS tasks to use the latest image?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ECR as a source, ECR generates an artifact file called 'imageDetail.json' which is of the format [1]. But the ECS Deploy stage requires a file called 'imagedefinitions.json' which is formatted differently [2].

To provide the required file, please add a CodeBuild step betweenn source and deploy with the following buildspec: (Basically converting the file)

```
version: 0.2
phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            docker: 18
    build:
        commands:
            - apt-get install jq -y
            - ContainerName="todo"
            - ImageURI=$(cat imageDetail.json | jq -r '.ImageURI')
            - printf '[{"name":"CONTAINER_NAME","imageUri":"IMAGE_URI"}]' > imagedefinitions.json
            - sed -i -e "s|CONTAINER_NAME|$ContainerName|g" imagedefinitions.json
            - sed -i -e "s|IMAGE_URI|$ImageURI|g" imagedefinitions.json
            - cat imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
    files:
        - imagedefinitions.json
```

#### Important1: Update 'ContainerName' as it exists in your task definition

#### Important2: Make sure input artifact of deploy action is BuildArtifact.

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/file-reference.html#file-reference-ecs-bluegreen
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/file-reference.html#pipelines-create-image-definitions